# How to keep repeating and executing a unit-test script until interruption in Python

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, infinite-loop, repeat

I would like to keep repeating/executing a script forever, until Ctrl+C is pressed. My code below doesn't work, it executes once and calls it finished. The .py file being executed is a unit test file.

```
import subprocess
import time

fileNames = [
    'KeepRepeatingThisFile.py' , 
    ]

try:
    while True:
        for i in fileNames:
            execfile(str(i))
            time.sleep(20)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Last few lines of KeepRepeatingThisFile.py:

```
# Execute test
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Why are you catching `KeyboardInterrupt`? Without it Crtl+C will kill the program anyway.

Comment: Not sure, what do you suggest. Although, that's not the cause of why my script doesn't do what I want I suppose